# Javascript xml query

Tags: javascript, xml

Is it possible for me to get an xml http object back and compare node info with a string i have and return that node? I would like to do this in JavaScript if possible. I dont know much about anything else. Thanks!

ex: All I want is the zip code out of this file. I have this xml saved as xmlHttpObjXip and know how to use the response xml but that is going to be alot of overhead.
file: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=44.5191590,-88.0198260&sensor=true

Comment: yes it is possible, but did you try anything so far

Comment: @refhat what do you mean try anything do far? If you meant so far, yes. I have tried using if loops and its gets out of my hands :/

Comment: sorry for the typo, if you post your code it will be helpful, i would say you need to add an id attribute to your xml and then loop through and compare this id attribute with a similarly defined id attribute in js, if successful match return zip, else break.

Comment: @refhat It's no problem. I posted an example of the xml file above, i cant edit it because it is coming from a google api.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) for this.

Construct a jQuery object from your `xmlHttpResponse`;

```
var $response = $(xmlHttpResponse);
```

You can then use the normal jQuery selectors to find the address node with the contents you require;

```
var $addressComponent = $response.find("type:contains('postal_code')").parent();
```

Here you get all the `type` nodes just as you might get all the `h1` nodes from HTML. Then from that set we get all the nodes that contain `postal_code`. The zip code is a sibling so we then get the parent to get all the zip code details.

You can then get the value you need from the node;

```
var zipCode = $addressComponent.find('long_name').text();
```

Here you get the `long_name` node from the `address_component` node and assign the text value for it to your zipCode variable.

One of the great abilities of jQuery is each call returns a jQuery object so you can chain all these calls together. This makes the code more efficient but harder to debug and not always more readable i.e. we can do all three steps above as;

```
var zipCode  = (xmlHttpResponse).find("type:contains('postal_code')").parent().find('long_name').text();
```

Comment: I really Appreciate the help Dave! However, im getting an error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Comment: @Troy have you included the jQuery library on the page that obtains the xmlHttpResponse? Check out http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#jQuery:_The_Basics